# Can I give an additional label for a TextView that's only announced by TalkBack, not shown visually?

Tags: android, textview, talkback, accessibility

Say I have a list of items, and one of the views in each item is a message, in a simple TextView, that is populated in code (dynamic data from a backend service).

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/message" 
    style="@style/DefaultText"                    
    />
```

Visually it doesn't need a label; the list item layout is pretty clear. But listening to how TalkBack reads the screen, I think it would be beneficial to have a "label" or description for it. So that TalkBack would read something like:

> Message: [the actual dynamic message content]

My question is: is it possible to add a label/description for a TextView that, firstly, *does not replace* the TextView content, but is read *along with it*, and secondly, *only affects TalkBack* (not the visual presentation)?

What I tried:

- `contentDescription` for the TextView. Doesn't work: if set, the actual content is not announced, *only* the `contentDescription`. Hmm, maybe if I'd set this in code with the description prepended to the actual content... but is there no easier way?
- Separate TextView with `labelFor` pointing to `@+id/message`. The problem is that it's also shown visually and screws up the design. If I make it not visible, one way or other, it seems TalkBack won't read it either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alright, I found two solutions! As mentioned in the question, I'd rather have avoided doing it in code, but it seems for optimal results that's the way to go.

#### Use `android:hint` in XML

The most simple way is to set `android:hint="Message"` for the TextView. TalkBack reads it *after* the actual text:

> [the actual dynamic message content] Message

For my needs, with the message being optional, this has some drawbacks: the hint is announced even if the TextView has no actual content (I'd prefer to omit it then), and in that case it's also shown visually (not what I want). Also, I'd prefer TalkBack to read the hint *before* the actual text.

#### Set `contentDescription` programmatically

Not as simple, but not complicated either, and you have complete control over what TalkBack says.

In my case, preferring to omit the description if message is missing and having it read *before* the message content, I'd do something like this in the code that populates the list items:

```
textView.setText(message);
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(message)) {        
    textView.setContentDescription(
        context.getString(R.string.message_desc, message));
}
```

With resource:

```
<string name="message_desc">Message: %s</string>
```

Comment: This is unstable behavior that you should not rely on. Hint attribute is for preview text in EditText boxes, any other behaviors on other controls is behavior that does not show up in AOSP test cases, and could vary widely by OS Version, and be patched and changed at any time. The contentDescription method is the way to go. Your external TextView method can work, just don't use visibility to hide, use height and width of 0. BUT, then this will show up in Focus Order, so you'll also have to modify the accessibilityTraveral attributes of controls around it. Stick with the contentDescription

Answer (score -3):

You can use this namespace it not visually show on real screen

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:text="your text"/>
```

Comment: Sure, not shown on real screen, but not read by TalkBack either! I guess you've misunderstood the question.

Comment: Tools namespace is just for the preview / design screen in Android Studio, it won't be included in compiled code

Answer (score -3):

In your XML file, set the importance to "no". You can also do this at run time using the View.setImportantForAccessibility() API.

```
android:importantForAccessibility="no"
```

Programmatically you can say:

```
view.setImportantForAccessibility(IMPORTANT_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY_NO);
```

[Example click here](http://www.apps4android.org/?p=3628)

[click here for more info](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setContentDescription(java.lang.CharSequence))

Comment: I think you've misunderstood my question. I'm aware of `importantForAccessibility` and I don't see how it could solve this.